# Pagination for div's

Tags: php, html

It is possible to have pagination for div's? Those div's are manually inputted thru text editor. I want to limit in 5 div's only and if its beyond the pagination will be displayed.

Comment: Your question does not make any sense. You cannot paginate divs

Answer (score 0):

You could accomplish something similar via custom javascript on the page. It would allow the user to move through the divs (five at a time) while remaining on the same page, similar to a carousel. The code would work something like this:

1. Hide all of the divs by default (via css)
2. On page load, loop through those divs and show the first five.
3. If there's more than 5, add some pagination links/buttons to allow the user to "page" through the still hidden divs.
4. When the user clicks one of those links/buttons, your code will again hide all the divs, then loop through them again, revealing the appropriate set of 5. So, for example if the user clicks on "page" 2, then your javascript needs to reveal divs #6-10.